# python application link models and views

Tags: python, user-interface, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I am trying to create a python gui application where I need an MVC like pattern to display and control models.

My issue is that I will create and modify the models over time and I need to create several different "view types" (like a form view on one window and a map view on an other), each "view type" should be able to show each of my models.

If I use an MVC pattern (which I am not even sure is relevant), I should then create a view-controller for each of my model and "view type". 
So if I create a new model, I will have to create a view-controller for each of the existing "view types", and if I want to create a new "view type" I will have to create a new view-controller for each model.

Creating a generic view is hard because the models are quite independant and differents.

Is there a good pattern or example I could use so I can make this smarter ? I'm stuck with this model / view design...
Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can this by using MVC. You don't have to create a lot of controllers for each model, you can just design `GET`-parameter like `?view=` or specify endpoint to read view type and after this to handle it in a single controllers.

Comment: oh so you mean using a single controller for a model with some kind of visitor in it ?

Comment: @bigboo it's up to you. You were talking about `view type`s. That what I was talking about too. Each `view type` can be handled with the parameter.